# Elasticsearch Map case insensitive to not_analyzed documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a type with following mapping

```
PUT /testindex
{
    "mappings" : {
        "products" : {
            "properties" : {
                "category_name" : {
                    "type" : "string",
                    "index" : "not_analyzed" 
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I wanted to search for an exact word.Thats why i set this as not_analyzed.
But the problem is i want to search that with lower case or upper case[case insensitive].

I searched for it and found a way to set case insensitive.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/testindex -d '{
  "mappings" : {
    "products" : {
      "properties" : {        
        "category_name":{"type": "string", "index": "analyzed", "analyzer":"lowercase_keyword"}
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Is there any way to do these two mappings to same field.?

Thanks..

Answer (score 38):

I think this example meets your needs:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/testindex/ -d '
{
  "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "analyzer_keyword":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter":"lowercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "test":{
        "properties":{
           "title":{
              "analyzer":"analyzer_keyword",
              "type":"string"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}'
```

taken from here: [How to setup a tokenizer in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079064/how-to-setup-a-tokenizer-in-elasticsearch)

it uses both the keyword tokenizer and the lowercase filter on a string field which I believe does what you want.

Comment: Hi, i have created an index with above settings and mappings. But its not working to my scenario. Because i want exact word match and case insensitive at the same time to same field. I used following query to search the exact word "Sithum". But it should search for "sithum". And also the index has records like "Sithum AA".But i want to get only "Sithum" POST /testindex/products/_search?pretty
{
"query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {                
                "term" : {  "category_name" : "Sithum"  }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: @user3683474 you can have your field analyzed (and possibly not_analyzed) in a different ways by using multi-field.

Comment: The above answer is correct for what the op wanted.. It behaves like a `not_analyzed` field except it is case insensitive.

Comment: Original text will lose the case if you follow this approach as it always gets converted to lowercase.

Comment: @geekprogrammer is it bad? what is the disadvantage? I though using standard analyzer uses also lowercase filter. Can you please explain your point with a sample maybe?

Comment: It is bad if you want to retain the original case. Though standard analyzer uses lowecase filter, it won't come into picture when your fields are not analyzed. If you want to both retain the original case and support case insesitive search then you need to use multi-fields(one with analyser(lowercase filter + keyword tokenizer) and one not_analyzed)..

Answer (score 6):

If you want case insensitive queries ONLY, consider changing both your data AND your query to either of lower/upper case before you go about doing your business.

That would mean you keep your field `not_analyzed` and enter data/query in only one of the cases.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this Gist answers your question best:
 * https://gist.github.com/mtyaka/2006966

You can index a field several times during mapping and we do this all the time where one is not_analyzed and another is. We typically set the not_analyzed version to `.raw`

Like John P. wrote, you can set up analyzer during runtime, or you can set one up in the config at server start like in link above:

```
# Register the custom 'lowercase_keyword' analyzer. It doesn't do anything else
# other than changing everything to lower case.
index.analysis.analyzer.lowercase_keyword.type: custom
index.analysis.analyzer.lowercase_keyword.tokenizer: keyword
index.analysis.analyzer.lowercase_keyword.filter: [lowercase]
```

Then you define your mapping for your field(s) with both the not_analyzed version and the analyzed one:

```
# Map the 'tags' property to two fields: one that isn't analyzed,
# and one that is analyzed with the 'lowercase_keyword' analyzer.
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/images/_mapping' -d '{
  "images": {
    "properties": {
      "tags": {
        "type": "multi_field",
        "fields": {
          "tags": {
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "lowercased": {
            "index": "analyzed",
            "analyzer": "lowercase_keyword",
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

And finally your query (note lowercased values before building query to help find match):

```
# Issue queries against the index. The search query must be manually lowercased.
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/myindex/images/_search?pretty=true' -d '{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "tags.lowercased": [
        "event:battle at the boardwalk"
      ]
    }
  },
  "facets": {
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags",
        "size": "500",
        "regex": "^team:.*"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 3):

just create your custom analyzer with `keyword` tokenizer and `lowercase` token filter.

Answer (score 3):

To this scenarios, I suggest that you could combine `lowercase filter` and `keyword tokenizer` into your custom analyzer. And lowercase your search-input keywords.

1.Create index with the analyzer combined with lowercase filter and keyword tokenizer

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/ -d '
{
  "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "your_custom_analyzer":{
                 "tokenizer":"keyword",
                 "filter": ["lowercase"]
              }
           }
        }
    }
}'
```

2.Put mappings and set the field properties with the `analyzer`

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_mappings/twitter -d '
{
    "twitter": {
        "properties": {
            "content": {"type": "string", "analyzer": "your_custom_analyzer" }
        }
    }
}'
```

3.You could search what you want in wildcard query.

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/twitter/ -d '{

    "query": {
        "wildcard": {"content": "**the words you want to search**"}
    }  
}'
```

Another way for search a filed in different way. I offser a suggestion for U was that using the multi_fields type.

You could set the field in `multi_field`

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test/_mapping/twitter -d '
{
    "properties": {
        "content": {
            "type": "multi_field",
            "fields": {
                "default": {"type": "string"},
                "search": {"type": "string", "analyzer": "your_custom_analyzer"}
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

So you could index data with above mappings properties. and finally search it in two way (default/your_custom_analyzer)

Answer (score 1):

We could achieve case insensitive searching on non-analyzed strings using ElasticSearch scripting.

**Example Query Using Inline Scripting:**

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {

            "must" : [{
                    "query_string" : {
                        "query" : "\"apache\"",
                        "default_field" : "COLLECTOR_NAME"
                    }
                }, {
                    "script" : {
                        "script" : "if(doc['verb'].value != null) {doc['verb'].value.equalsIgnoreCase(\"geT\")}"
                    }
                }
            ]

        }
    }
}
```

You need to [enable scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#modules-scripting) in the elasticsearch.yml file. Using scripts in search queries could reduce your overall search performance. If you want scripts to perform better, then you should make them "native" using java plugin.

**Example Plugin Code:**

```
public class MyNativeScriptPlugin extends Plugin {

    @Override
    public String name() {
        return "Indexer scripting Plugin";
    }


    public void onModule(ScriptModule scriptModule) {
        scriptModule.registerScript("my_script", MyNativeScriptFactory.class);

    }

    public static class MyNativeScriptFactory implements NativeScriptFactory {

        @Override
        public ExecutableScript newScript(@Nullable Map<String, Object> params) {
            return new MyNativeScript(params);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean needsScores() {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static class MyNativeScript extends AbstractSearchScript {
        Map<String, Object> params;

        MyNativeScript(Map<String, Object> params) {
            this.params = params;
        }

        @Override
        public Object run() {
            ScriptDocValues<?> docValue = (ScriptDocValues<?>) doc().get(params.get("key"));
            if (docValue instanceof Strings) {
                return ((String) params.get("value")).equalsIgnoreCase(((Strings) docValue).getValue());
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example Query Using Native Script:**

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {

            "must" : [{
                    "query_string" : {
                        "query" : "\"apache\"",
                        "default_field" : "COLLECTOR_NAME"
                    }
                }, {
                    "script" : {
                        "script" : "my_script",
                        "lang" : "native",
                        "params" : {
                            "key" : "verb",
                            "value" : "GET"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it is so simple, just create mapping as follows

```
{
    "mappings" : {
        "products" : {
            "properties" : {
                "category_name" : {
                    "type" : "string" 
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

No Need of giving index if you want to work with case insensitive because the default index will be "standard" that will take care of case insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

I wish I could add a comment, but I can't. So the answer to this question is "**this is not possible**".

> Analyzers are composed of a single Tokenizer and zero or more TokenFilters.

I wish I could tell you something else, but spending 4 hours researching, that's the answer. I'm in the same situation. You can't skip tokenization. It's either all on or all off.