# elasticsearch case insensitive term filter search on not_analyzed field

Tags: elasticsearch, case-insensitive

There are similar questions asked here [Elasticsearch Map case insensitive to not_analyzed documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24036708/elasticsearch-map-case-insensitive-to-not-analyzed-documents), however mine is a slightly different because I deal with special characters.

Most people recommend using a `keyword analyzer` combined with `lowercase filter`. However, this does not work for my case because keyword analyzer tokenizes on spaces, and special characters like `^, #, etc`. which break the type of support I'm going for.

i.e.

1. `^HELLOWORLD` should be matched by searching `^helloworld`, but not `helloworld`
2. `#FooBar` should be matched by `#foobar` but not `foobar`.
3. `Foo Bar` should be matched by `foo bar`, but not `foo` or `bar`.

Similar functionality with what we see here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html#_term_filter_with_numbers, but with case insensitivity.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

### EDIT 1:

It seems the core of my problem was with multi-field, as keyword+lowercase seems to resolve the question posed in the title. However, it would be more accurate to pose this question for a multi-field value property.

test_mapping.json:

```
{
  "properties" : {
    "productID1" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "index_analyzer" :  "keyword_lowercase",
      "search_analyzer" : "keyword_lowercase"
    },
    "productID2" : {
      "type": "multi_field",
      "keyword_edge_ID": {
        "type": "string", 
        "index_analyzer":"keyword_lowercase_edge", 
        "search_analyzer":"keyword_lowercase_edge"
      },
      "productID2": {
        "type": "string", 
        "index": "analyzed", 
        "store": "yes", 
        "index_analyzer":"keyword_lowercase", 
        "search_analyzer":"keyword_lowercase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

test.json:

```
{
  "index": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter":{
        "edgengramfilter": {
          "type": "edgeNgram",
          "side": "front",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 32
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "keyword_lowercase" : {
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        },
        "keyword_lowercase_edge": {
            "tokenizer": "keyword",
            "filter": ["lowercase", "edgengramfilter"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Shell script to create index with mappings:

```
#!/bin/sh

ES_URL="http://localhost:9200"

curl -XDELETE $ES_URL/test
curl -XPOST $ES_URL/test/ --data-binary @test.json
curl -XPOST $ES_URL/test/query/_mapping --data-binary @test_mapping.json
```

POST `localhost:9200/test/query`:

```
{ 
  "productID1" : "^A",
  "productID2" : "^A" 
}
```

I'd like it so that I can match against productID2 with "^A", but it is returning no results right now, but it works when I do the same query against productID1. `{"query": { "match": { "productID2": "^A" }}}`

Comment: Not sure this helps, but my limited experience is that ES filters are case sensitive on not-analyzed fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the example below, the `keyword` *tokenizer* and `lowercase` filter is doing exactly that - it lowercases the entire value while preserving all spaces and special characters. The example of how to use it can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24044636/783043).

```
curl "localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty&tokenizer=keyword&filters=lowercase" -d "^HELLOWORLD"
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "^helloworld",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 11,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}

curl "localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty&tokenizer=keyword&filters=lowercase" -d "#FooBar"    
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "#foobar",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}

curl "localhost:9200/_analyze?pretty&tokenizer=keyword&filters=lowercase" -d "Foo Bar"
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "foo bar",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Hmm, you seem to be right. I actually simplified my example down a lot from what's in our live code. For some reason, I'm having C also hit against ^C, even though the field has they keyword and lowercase filter analyzer. My only other hunch is that the field is technically a multi-field, so it could be causing some issues. Let me update my OP to provide those details

Comment: Perhaps, you are not specifying the field in your search and instead searching _all fields, which is analyzed using standard analyzer.

Comment: I've updated the original post with a more detailed configuration of my system. I seem to be messing up the design of the multi-field with this analyzer

Comment: I spotted the problem. I didn't have the "fields": { ... } around my two fields. Adding it seemed to address the problem.