# Kibana: Case-insensitive display of data

Tags: case-insensitive, uppercase, kibana, lowercase

Is there a way for Kibana to only display data once for both lowercase and uppercase matches?

For example, say I need a pie chart of exceptions, I would not want both "BusinessException" and "businessexception" to be displayed and to be considered different.

Comment: I can only think of it as you type inside the query of kibana BusinessException AND businessexception For filtering u can do that but not for query.

Answer (score 6):

There's no way to do this with Kibana. However, you can do this at the elasticsearch level with a [tokeniser](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html). You'd set up something like this:

```
$ curl -XPUT localhost:9200/testindex/ -d '
{
  "settings":{
     "index":{
        "analysis":{
           "analyzer":{
              "case_insensitive_analyser":{
                 "tokenizer":"case_insensitive",
                 "filter":"uppercase"
              }
           }
        }
     }
  },
  "mappings":{
     "test":{
        "properties":{
           "exception":{
              "analyzer":"case_insensitive_analyser",
              "type":"string"
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

which I borrowed from this question: [How to setup a tokenizer in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079064/how-to-setup-a-tokenizer-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would setting up a tokeniser at the elasticsearch level prevent Kibana from having multiple displays depending on lowercase/uppercase?

Comment: This is the correct way to go and by far the simplest.