# Elasticsearch regexp with space not working

Tags: javascript, regex, elasticsearch, whitespace

Let's assume I have books with titles indexed with **ElasticSearch** as following:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_river/books/_meta" -d'
{
"type": "jdbc",
"jdbc": {
"driver": "org.postgresql.Driver",
"url": "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/...",
"user": "...",
"password": "...",
"index": "books",
"type": "books",
"sql": "SELECT * FROM books"}
```

}'

For instance, I have a book called `"Afoo barb"`.

The following code (searching for `'.*foo.*'`) returns well the book:

```
client.search({
  index: 'books',
  'from': 0,
  'size': 10,
  'body' : {
    'query': {
      'filtered': {
         'filter': {
           'bool': {
              'must': {
                'regexp': { title: '.*foo.*' }
               }
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
});
```

But the following code (searching for `'.*foo bar.*'`) does not:

```
client.search({
  index: 'books',
  'from': 0,
  'size': 10,
  'body' : {
    'query': {
      'filtered': {
         'filter': {
           'bool': {
              'must': {
                'regexp': { title: '.*foo bar.*' }
               }
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
});
```

I tried to replace the space by `'\s'` or `'.*'` but it does not work either.

I think the title is separated in terms (`['Afoo', 'barb']`) so it can't find `'.*foo bar.*'`.

How can I ask Elasticsearch to search the regexp in the complete title ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Elasticsearch will apply the regexp to the terms produced by the tokenizer for that field, and not to the original text of the field.

You can use different [tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html) for indexing your fields or define the regex in such a way that it returns required documents with high score.

Example with keyword tokenizer:

```
'regexp': { title: '*(foo bar)*' }
```

Comment: `'.*(foo|bar).*'` does not work since it does an union between the result of `'.*foo.*'` and `'.*bar.*'`. I rather want an intersection because I don't want the title `'Foo baz'`...

Comment: What tokenizer should I use to search against the entire original text ?

Comment: @pidupuis you can use [keyword tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) for your purpose..

Comment: Thanks but I don't manage to use it... According to things I read on forums, I tried to add it as a settings when putting the index or directly use it as param in a `query_string` but it does not work and I don't find any explicit documentation...

Comment: @pidupuis have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15079064/how-to-setup-a-tokenizer-in-elasticsearch)?

Comment: How can I combine this with the river syntax ?

Comment: What do you mean by river syntax?.. Also.. rivers are [deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating_rivers) in 1.5.0.

Comment: Ok so I am not using rivers anymore. I create my index through javascript using the `keyword` tokenizer. `'filter': {bool: {must: { regexp: { title: '.*foo bar.*' }}}}` does not work but `'query' : { 'query_string' : { 'fields' : ['title'], 'query' : '*foo bar*'}}` does so it's good :)