# Kibana4 regex not working as expcted

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

```
My Regex: OPPO\sR7.*
```

It works in scala and can match "OPPO R7" or "OPPO R7sm" and so on.

But it does not work in kibana4.I use it like `base.model:/OPPO\sR7.*/` in kibana4.

Who can help me.Thank you!

Comment: Try just `OPPO R7.*`

Comment: It does not work,too. But thanks.

Comment: It means you have an issue somewhere else. The regex is basic, and should work. Most probably, you need to remove delimiters: `base.model: 'OPPO R7.*'`

Comment: It works when i use  base.model: 'OPPO R7.*' ,but I get  some result like "OPPO A53" ,I only want get "OPPOP R7" or "OPPOP R7sm" and so on.

Comment: This is because space tokenizes the string into two.

Comment: @Richa 
you are right. but how can i control it as a whole.

Comment: Also, see [this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30380411/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in following. It worked for me. Hope it works for you too

```
name: OPPO AND R7.*
```

Notice removed quotes and `AND` operator.

Comment: It does not work for me.I also get "OPPO A3" and so on. But,i will keep on trying.

Comment: Which version of elasticsearch are you using?