# Kibana : Cannot query with regex having space

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a field as

```
author
Jason Pete
Jason Paul
Mike Yard
Jason Voorhies
```

in kibana 4.4 i am querying as

```
author:/Jason.*/
```

so i get all records for

```
Jason Pete
Jason Paul
Jason Voorhies
```

fine, now i want to do

```
author:/Jason P.*/
```

i expect

```
Jason Pete
Jason Paul
```

but i get

```
No Records found :(
```

what is wrong with my regex? Is there another way to specify the space character after Jason? I even tried

```
author:/Jason\sP.*/
```

but still no results

Comment: Perhaps, related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379094/elasticsearch-regexp-with-space-not-working/30380411#30380411

Comment: thanks, but the problem is that i want part of the second word, hence grouping the two would not make sense

Answer (score 4):

This is because your `author` field is probably analyzed, and thus, the value `Jason Pete` gets tokenized into two tokens `jason` and `pete`. Hence, it is not possible to query both values.

If you want to change that behavior, I suggest you create a multi-field out of the `author` field, with a `not_analyzed` sub-field, like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/my_type -d '{
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "author": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {                  <--- add this section to author your field
            "raw": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}'
```

Once your mapping is updated (make sure to replace `my_index` and `my_type` with whatever index and mapping type name you have), you need to re-index your data and then you'll be able to query the `author.raw` field in Kibana like this:

```
author.raw:/Jason P.*/
```

Comment: thanks @Val, but my field is not analyzed in the mapping.

Comment: Can you show your mapping with `curl -XGET localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/my_type`

Comment: although the OP's is not analyzed and therefore this answer is less relevant to that, IMHO this is __the__ solution that most of the searchers will need when entering this SO thread, so upvote

Answer (score 1):

It does work for me with:

```
    author:/Jason\ P.*/
```

So backslash-space `\s` works for space in my case, `ES1.7` and `Kibana4.1.2`.